# Using php json_decode with 1d and 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using json_decode in PHP to decode a JSON object which may have 1d array or 2d array for a value:

```
{"Cell":{"@column":"ZjE6dW5pdmVyc2l0eQ==","@timestamp":"1425598820484","$":"MC44MDc2NDEwNDg0MjI5MjMy"}}
```

or

```
{"Cell":[{"@column":"ZjE6YQ==","@timestamp":"1425599309809","$":"MC4wNTYzMzgwMjgxNjkwMTQwODY="},{"@column":"ZjE6YW5k","@timestamp":"1425599309809","$":"MC4wNTYzMzgwMjgxNjkwMTQwODY="},{"@column":"ZjE6Y2F0Y2hlcw==","@timestamp":"1425599309809","$":"MC4wNDIyNTM1MjExMjY3NjA1Ng=="},{"@column":"ZjE6aQ==","@timestamp":"1425599309809","$":"MC4wOTg1OTE1NDkyOTU3NzQ2NA=="},{"@column":"ZjE6dGhhdA==","@timestamp":"1425599309809","$":"MC4xNjkwMTQwODQ1MDcwNDIyNQ=="}]}
```

and I am using $Cell = $json["Cell"] to access the elements. The problem I am facing is that the second case plays nicely and I get an array of arrays while the first one should be a single element array but is being interpreted as a 3 element array.

Comment: The first one as it is now is not a valid JSON.

Comment: So it's an object with 3 elements. In terms of php it's an associative array with 3 elements.

Comment: Agreed. The first one is an associative array of three elements.But the second one is an array of 5 arrays each of which have 3 elements. Is there any way I can check for the first case and handle it separately or any way to use $json["Cell"] in both cases?

Comment: Oh, actually the first one is still invalid JSON

Comment: Ouch sorry about that. This definitely passes JSONLint.

Comment: Well the ideal answer is to always make `Cell` an collection (Array) of objects even if there is only one. The easiest solution after that is to not pass `true` as the second arg to json decode which will inerpret js Objects as `stdClass` then you can do `$cell = (array) $response->Cell;` and make it an array with one element on the PHP side. Of course that can complicate navigating more complex structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just check if the element has the key? Like this:

```
if (isset($json['Cell']['@column']) {
    // do stuff with single-element
} else {
    // it is a collection
}
```

Comment: This does seem like the simplest way to go about things and it works. Though I did use is_array rather than isset.